# Minimum value of $n$ such that $nq+k$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Given two primes $p$ and $q$ where $q > p$ and a positive integer $k<q$, if $nq+k$ is divisible by $p$ then what's the minimum value of $n$ if one such $n$ exists?

Also do there exist any $k$ such that $nq+k$ is never divisible by $p$ for any $n$? If such $k$ exists how to find that?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, Dirichlet's theorem on prime in arithmetic progressions tells us that if $q$ does not divide $k$ then there exists $n$ such that $p$ divides $nq+k$.

Comment: q does not divide k. In fact k < q. I have updated my question. So such n always exist ? But how to find that n ? That's the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bezout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we have $\gcd(p,q)=1 \Rightarrow \exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $$xp+yq=1 \tag{1}$$ or 
$$kxp+kyq=k \Rightarrow p \mid (-ky)q+k \tag{2}$$
Moreover, if $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfies $(1)$ then $(x_0+tq,y_0-tp)$ satisfies $(1)$ as well, $\forall t\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $(kx_0+ktq,ky_0-ktp)$ will satisfy $(2)$ and $n_t=ktp-ky_0$. As a result, there will be an infinity of $n_t$ s.t. $p \mid n_tq+k$, both positive and negative. So, looking for a minimum may be troublesome, unless we are looking for a positive minimum.

This also answers the 2nd question, no such $k$ exists. If it existed, all of the above would lead to an immediate contradiction.

Comment: Yes n is always positive. And I am looking for a positive minimum

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article I posted. You will see the boundary for $\min |y|$ there from which it should be easy to deduce the boundary for $\min |n_t|$.

Comment: Sorry I have gone through that page and I could not deduce any analytical form to figure out the minimum n. Can you please include that in your answer ?

Comment: Like $|y|\leq \left|\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\right|$? Only in this case it's $|n|\leq \left|qk\right|$

Comment: For Eq 1 to hold either of x or y has to be negetive. Because both p and q are positive. However in my problem everything is positive integer. I can't understand how it relates my problem.

Comment: Of course, one will be negative and one will be positive, but with $(x_0+tq,y_0−tp), \forall t\in\mathbb{Z}$ (!!!) you can reverse the signs. All you need is a positive $x$ and a negative $y$, then $n=(−ky)$ is positive. Right?

Comment: I understand how you relate Extended Euclid's Algorithm to this. $mp+(-n)q=k$ for some $m$ in my equations. But what next ? now there are 2 unknowns $m, n$. However minimum n will result to minimum m and vice verse. But Can you use only three unknowns $p,q,k$ and represent $Min(n)$ analytically in a single equation ? Also do you use $\vert \_ \vert$ to denote $Min(\_)$ ? And $p \vert$ to denote "for some p" ?

Comment: Yes, except $n$ may not necessarily be $0$. Look at the problem in smaller steps. **Step 1** using Bezout, establish existence of $(m_0, n_0)$ s.t. $m_0 p +(-n_0)q=k$.  **Step 2** show that $m=m_0 +tq$, $n=n_0+tp$ also satisfy $mp+(-n)q=k$. And then you have $m$ for $\forall n>0$.